# get variable number of leading zero from excel to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, spreadsheet

### Problem

I have problem with import data from excel to rails.
i wanna import some data that leading by zero number from excel to Rails,
I using spreadsheet gem,and Rails 3

### What I already tried

and in excel i already tried using (') in front of number.
example, in excel i put '009111111 
But when i import it to my application, only get 9111111

### Question

what i need is the whole number.
What i missed?

anyone can help me?

P.S = Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your values in excel with single quotes?

You said you tried `'009111111` but what about `'009111111'`

Comment: What i get is `'0091111111'`, what i wnat is `0091111111`

Answer (score 1):

In excel, right click on the cell you want to format (or the column/row), and click "Format Cells". Select "Custom" for "Category" on the left-hand side, and in the "Type" input type a zero for the total number of spaces you want. This will zero-pad all of the numbers in the selected range to the specified number of digits.

Screenshot attached for viewing pleasure.[image]

Comment: Thanks Dude,
But the problem is, my data don't have consistent length, so i can't decide the length of number